# Are we authorized to send Google Map screenshot via email on Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, authorization, screenshot

I was wondering if Google authorized an app to take a screenshot of a Google Map in an Android application and then letting the user send the screenshot via e-mail. I can't find the information I need so I am asking here on stack overflow.

Please note that the email is generated by the application (text, images, etc) but the user has to send the email through his configured email client in Android.

If they don't allow this, is there a way to contact Google and make some sort of an arrangement?

Thanks a lot!
- Sam :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, Google is pretty cool about you sharing their services.  But you have to make sure you check out their branding and trademarks.  As long as all of that is in order, you can do whatever you want.

In short, don't make it appear, in any manner, that you own or produced that stuff.  It was generated by Google.  It is owned by Google.  As long as you make that clear, you will have no problems.

A good example of this is, say, you print a business card advertising your app on Google Play.  Make sure that Android(tm) has a trademark.  Make sure that you make a disclaimer at the bottom saying "Android is a trademark of Google, inc.".  As long as you do that, you have satisfied their brand requirement.

Comment: how sure are you about that. You have any references? I´m  currently searching in the docs for a confirmation of that, but can´t find anything related. And does the same applies to the static api?

Comment: I am sure as Google searches tell me.  All you have to do is search about how and when you can use their materials.  It is all explained.  Here is one simple search with a page FULL of information:  https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=google%20branding%20guidelines

Comment: I understand we must give Google credit for using their material. And @MorrisonChang 's answer of having a lawyer taking the time to check out the terms of services could be a good idea. 

I am not necessarily being paid or even expected to read documents I do not have the knowledge to fully understand.

PS. The snapshot that we take is using Google's API, so it contains a google watermark, logo, etc.

Comment: It appears that they already have protected themselves then.  So, really, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: @durbnpoisn True, but I also read somewhere that Map snapshots should not be sent to other users. You should send data to recreate the map instead. However, this is not realistic for our use case, so that's why I was wondering about taking a snapshot of the map.

Comment: I think that falls under the heading of "best practice" more than a legal issue.  But, then, it might because they don't want the data to be displayed incorrectly.  In either case, I still think you're ok.  Especially since you "read somewhere" but cannot find that source to verify it now.  I'm guessing that if you could, you wouldn't be asking about it.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! I appreciate it very much. I'd upvote your answers but I can't upvote because my reputation is too low... Have a great day though!

Comment: The accepted answer is fine.  Glad I could help.  Best of luck to you!